# Windroy Android Emulator: Having error- could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB, failed to create context 0*3005

Tags: windows-7, android-emulator

I searched for the first error in stack, but I got that the error is resolved using the AVD manager, and they were using the Android studio, but in my case i'm using windroy so there is no AVD editor or manager.
How to resolve this problem please suggest.

[image: Screen shot of the windroy window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in android studio there is an avd editor...

Your error is one of the following:

1.Not enough RAM assigned to the avd, should be 756megs or higher

2. You have an old video graphics driver and need to update